# MSR90 magnetic card reader inserting '3' between each letter

Tags: magnetic-cards

I am trying to integrate a USB magnetic card reader Osayde MSR90 with my web app. However when I read the card it inserts '3' between each letter. 
i.e. i'm getting `c3x3m3i3k3e3` instead of `cxmike`.
I tried it on OSX and Windows machines.

Does anybody have any experience with this?

Comment: I can only guess that maybe is some sort of flow control that the two sides dont agree on...  IE emulated rs232 with software flow control... just guessing though

Comment: no idea. there are no drivers for it that i could find, and there are no settings for it in the System Settings other than basic keyboard settings. so I can't even adjust any flow controls

Comment: it probably presents itself as a keyboard... you can try different keyboard preferences to see if any of them work

Comment: it does. and i tried all 3 of the available options - same result

Comment: looks like they have some support options on their warranty page: http://osayde.com/801-2/

Comment: Yes, but I figured SO community is smarter and respond faster :)